# Birth-death Process/Extinction

Tags: probability, statistics, random-walk

Random processes in Continuous time.
Given that $\beta = \frac{4}{5}*\mu$ I have calculated that the birth rate $= 0.4$ and the death rate $= 0.5$.

If the initial population $X(0)=6$, how many events (births and deaths) are there until the population dies out?

This is an embedded process $\{X_n;\:n=0,1,...\}$.

Is this possible to work out with so little information?
It's all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_n$ be the number of events until extinction given that $X(0)=n$. Then, $N_0=0$ and conditioning on the next event, we have for $n\geq 1$,

\begin{align}
& N_n = 1 + \dfrac{4}{9}N_{n+1} + \dfrac{5}{9}N_{n-1} \\
\text{or, re-arranging, }\qquad & 4N_{n+1} - 9N_n + 5N_{n-1} = -9 \qquad\qquad(1).
\end{align}

Note also that to reach $0$ from state $n$ requires going in turn to states $n-1,n-2,\ldots,0,$ and the number of events in each of these sub-paths has the same distribution as $N_1$, independently of the number of events in the other sub-paths. This means that,

$$N_n = nN_1.$$

Substituting this into $(1)$ gives:

\begin{align}
-9 &= 4(n+1)N_1 - 9nN_1 + 5(n-1)N_1 \\
&= -N_1 \\
\therefore\quad N_1 &= 9.
\end{align}

So we have the solution $N_n = 9n$ and in particular our required value is $N_6 = 54$.

Comment: Thank you. Although I have just realised that in my question I have p+q does not equal 1. The beta value does give those p and q values but that is due to calculator rounding errors. I will use your method with the exact values instead i.e. p=4/9 and q=5/9.

Comment: @C.Watt Yes, I got the probabilities/rates wrong. I've fixed that now. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, your answer was correct with the decimal probabilities. I've worked it out with the fractions too now and also got N(6)=54. Thanks again.

Comment: @C.Watt Yes, I think it's correct now (54). Before I had answer 30 using the wrong probabilities.